# Testing Azure Stream Analytics Job not working (Error on send)

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, microsoft-documentation

I'm trying to complete the tutorial of Azure Stream Analytics that using an app provided by Microsoft docs to send data to Azure Event Hub, to be simple, I'm just following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-manage-job).

Now I got stuck at the step: "Start the event generator application"

What I have done is:

- Create the Azure Event Hub & Azure Event Hub Namespace
- Create the policy at "Shared access policies" (as below)

[image]

- Update the  element in the config file (telcodatagen.exe.config, as below)

The below file can be download [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/D/8BD50991-8D54-4F59-AB83-3354B69C8A7E/TelcoGenerator.zip).

[image]

Here are the values I filled in at the shelter in the previous image:

```
<add key="EventHubName" value="***My Event Hubs Namespace***"/>
<add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="***My Connection string–primary key without the EntityPath value***"/>
```

But when I run the below command at CMD:

```
telcodatagen.exe 1000 0.2 2
```

I got an error as the figure below (error on send: one or more error occurred):

[image]

I'm completely brand new to Azure Event Hub and Azure Stream Analytics and I can guarantee to follow the steps of the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-manage-job), but I am not sure what the error is, why this error occurs and how to debug.

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to contain actual formatted text, not images (see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) for reasons why this is really important). Also: Please include the complete values you're using in your settings (of course, substitute a fake namespace and key) - based on your screenshot, it's hard to tell what values you've actually used.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the necessary information (EventHubName and Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString)

Comment: If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ConnectionString` is wrong.

You should get it from namespace,not Instance.
[image]

And `EventHubName` is your Event Hubs Instance's name.

By the way,you can download c# code from [Github](https://github.com/croja02/TelcoGenerator).

Hope this can help you:).

Answer (score 0):

Two things to fix:

1. This needs to be set to the entity name not "Event Hubs Namespace".

`<add key="EventHubName" value="***My Event Hubs Namespace***"/>`

2. Remove trailing ; at the end if there is one.

`<add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="***My Connection string–primary key without the EntityPath value***"/`>

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues & downloaded the source as per Steve's comment.

I couldn't build as it targeted .Net 4.5.1

Gave up, used [this blog post](https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/send-events-to-event-hub) to build my own Event Sender

Another alternative might be try downloading .Net 4.5.1 Developer Pack & debug?